# What are the differences in using GitHub or GitLab for CI/CD?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, gitlab, devops, continuous-deployment

I have a software project which is currently hosted on BitBucket. I would like to implement a CI/CD pipeline which would have to run on local agents for build/test/deploy. The runners would also have to be compatibile with Windows 7/10 (x86/x64) and Linux (x86/x64/arm64/armv7). I am pretty new to DevOps, but after a thorough search, I came up with 2 options: GitHub and GitLab. Can you present to me which one would be better, exposing some advantages/disadvantages for each one? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be you go with `GitLab` because of some of the following reasons.

1. `GitLab CI` has been in the market for a much longer time than `GitHub actions` that was announced in Nov of 2019 you can see some of the feature comparisons on GitLab blog [here](https://about.gitlab.com/devops-tools/github-vs-gitlab/)
2. When you are getting started It is much easier to navigate the `GitLab` GUI to configure all the tools that you need for `DevOps`  in comparison to `GitHub's` somewhat difficult to navigate GUI due to the number of other tools that are available on `GitHub`
3. In addition `GitLab` is primarily focused on improving `DevOps` and as a result, they have integrated a couple of features over time in line with making the whole entire DevOps process much smoother than GitHub which just jumped started out in 2019.
4. Also there are a bunch of templates available for you to get started on `GitLab` which is not the case in `GitHub`.Plus these templates are in a wide range of languages which I am sure to cover your project requirements
5. Ease of access of `CI` within `GitLab` well in addition to having an easy to navigate GUI `GitLab` has all the tools necessary for your DevOps bundled in one location so every single DevOps feature that you will need will be accessible in this one place and in addition to that they do have a YAML template available for you that can help you get started quickly.
6. Finally there are way more features within `GitLab` majorly because it has been in the market since 2012 or 2011 compared to `GitHub actions` of 2019

There are however some major similarities that I would also like to point out which I believe could make your transition easier or just in case you want to try out both tools to judge for yourself.

1. Both `GitHub Actions` and `GitLab Ci` are build-in tools.
2. Both `GitHub` and `GitLab` use the same commands so there will not be a learning curve for you in terms of managing and collaborating changes on your project.